# Is there an issue with Arduino IDE (1.8.15) in calculating dynamic memory when compiling the code?

Tags: arduino, dynamic-memory-allocation

I run below code for Arduino Uno and it compiled successfully. But I am expecting an error since I have used uint32_t data type for the variables. It should exceed the dynamic memory, right? Because I have used 1000 uint32_t. But it just consumes 13 bytes. Why?

```
uint32_t x;
uint32_t data[1000];

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
data[x++]=x; 
}
```

Arduino console log
*Sketch uses 482 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 13 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2035 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.*